# Why am I getting a "USER NOT AUTHENTICATED" error when I try to send email from an app running on Heroku?

Tags: authentication, email

What are the best authentication plans for emails and login on Heroku and how do they work?

My setup environment is web js and node.js server but I would like to understand the whole process including email mx and dns especially via web applet providers like Heroku.

I tried changing my DNS SPF declaration. I want to understand why I get this 
`smtp: '-ERR USER NOT AUTHENTICATED` message.

Is it from the Heroku servers? How can I let the message arrive to email?

Comment: The question is a bit vague -- are you asking about how to send email from an app that is running on Heroku and wondering why you are getting the error message or are you interested in how web apps can send eMail when running on platforms like Heroku?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jay, I am looking for primarily the first. It seems that a wider understanding of how all the process work will enable that as well.

Here is some more information. Email fails to authenticate with "mail" and "rcpt" authentication smtp failure messages from gmail and zoho at my heroku login console. The server app is node.js on heruko I feel that if i to buy gmail from google app it will work. my platform the registrar is name.com and there is possibly a block there. The mx recs and spf seem to be setup correctly. Even the test file won't pass.

Comment: Are you using an external SMTP service? (See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/smtp)

Comment: also look at <http://www.azgaard.com/2012/06/05/sending-email-from-rails-using-smtp-on-heroku/>. BTW, this question is not a programming question -- it is more of a system administration question. I have flagged this question for migration to SuperUser.com

Comment: ok i am still working on it i will let you know for any success so far i found there was some client incosistancy as well do you think that could affect the answer. Another thing is that I don't have google app installed. and another this is that there are two google analytics on that page is that legal for google? sorry for this mess there are alot of technologies at once: ajax jquerry email and validation authenticaton which im new to. I will migrate to sendgrid and try that after i enable validator engine.